# Encountered some bad UX the other day

Tags: riddle

> You press down to get it up

Sometimes everyday-life riddles you. What am I talking about?

(Probably not bad UX but I remember the first time I encountered it and I remember being a bit confused (I was quite young), my brain is used to the convention now)

Comment: Judging from the answers, this question is a little 'broad'. Could you give something more to narrow it down a little?

Comment: 'Correct' answer has already been given, but cannot accept within 10 min. I agree it's broad, It'll drop away soon. I leave it as is. I actually tried some to make it a proper riddle, but they all came out boring and convoluted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> An elevator button?

Because

> You press the down button to call the elevator up (if it is currently below you).

Comment: Comment on riddle being to broad: Hmm I maybe should've had the same riddle but the question to go along with it could've been 'Where are you?' --> top floor

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> pressing on the weighing scale?

as

> you push down(apply more pressure) and it will go up(weight)

It can also be,

> bread in toaster (or may be I am just hungry)

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> a Pedal bin?

because

> You press the pedal down and the bin lid goes up.

Why the UX (user experience) fits in.

> You don't have to get your hands dirty to dispose of your trash.

Comment: it can also be pedal on bicycle (only one pedal)? so other one goes up

Comment: Bicycle pedals aren't that confusing for little children, are they?

Comment: I guess you are right, but as a child, i was amazed, after seeing them work first time

Answer (score 1):

I know there's already an accepted answer, but this fits quite well too:

> A website with a scrollbar.

Because..

> If you press `down` on your keyboard, the contents of the website itself move up.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> A trampoline (or any spring-device like a Pogo stick)

Because

> In order to go up, you need to put pressure down